# How to use Custom user type in hibernate cfg file?

Tags: hibernate

I have created my custom user type MyUserType which append some value to every string it get. I can apply this user type to every column using annotation.
Now i want to know , how can i achieve the same thing if i am using hibernate configuration file rather than annotations.

Comment: I can apply this custom type using                          @TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "encodedString", typeClass = EncodedStringUserType.class)
})                                                                       Class MyClass {                                                           @org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "encodedString")    String Name;

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/manual/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-custom